# I bought a brand new 26” Seachange beach cruiser that only has the brake in back tire rim when pushing pedals backwards! I am putting a motor kit on

Tags: conversion, coaster, motor

As I started this project first thing I needed to do was pull the back tire off, remove the brake arm from the rim to be able to put the wheel for the motor chain on! Ok I was able to do said process but when I went to put the rear rim back on the bike I wasn’t able to pedal or have the tire move after Reassembly. My question is simply, what did I do wrong and how to I remedy(fix) this issue????? I have tried pulling the brake arm lose so as to not have overtighten the Bearings but it’s not finding a happy medium between not moving or to lose, please tell me how to fix my expensive project!!

Comment: Can you post some photos - it makes it much easier to diagnose a problem when we can see it.

Comment: Just don't do it. Get a real moped.

Comment: @ojs moped? Why? The wording isn't clear but this could easily be about an e-bike conversion kit, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to fit (if problematic when the bike has a coaster brake as this might)

Comment: What kind of rear brake does this bike have (coaster brake? Rim brake?)? What kind of gears/transmission? What exactly did you do (did you remove the axle, maybe causing problems with the ball bearings?)? Photos would help ...

Comment: @ChrisH I think the parts about "remove the brake arm" and "brake in back tire time when pushing pedals backwards!" are really difficult to interpret as anything else than coaster brake. It's just the general level of mechanical knowledge that gives me the feeling that maybe this isn't the right person to DIY with anything that involves motors.

Comment: As far as I understand the question it's a back-pedalling brake

Comment: @ojs it sounds more like a coaster brake than anything on a motor vehicle, and the reference to "rim"  doesn't make sense in any context - but if we replace "rim" with "hub" it's self consistent. And there are references to pedalling

Comment: @ChrisH yes, it sounds like coaster brake on a bicycle, but it might actually be a coaster brake on a bicycle. Which the person is trying to turn into a motor vehicle. The person probably calls the entire wheel "rim".

Comment: @ojs "motor" rather than "engine" is probably electric, though there are some nasty conversions using lawnmower engines and a separate drive chain.  We've got a new contributor who's having a bit of difficulty with terminology - there's no need to be dismissive while it's unclear

Comment: @branden could you give some more info please?  Is this a coaster brake?  Is this an electric or liquid motor kit?  How does the motor connect to the transmission/wheel?  A couple of photos [edit] into your question might help a lot.  Otherwise the question risks being closed as "needing more details"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your bike has a coaster brake, that is activated by pedalling backward.

Coaster brakes need a "reaction arm" which is secured to the frame to function.  You say you removed the arm and presumably left the attachment point free to spin.  I suspect this lug has moved to actuate the coaster brake all the time.

One fix is to remove the rear wheel, disassemble the hub, and remove the brake shoes.  They will look like two rough lumps of metal, approximately cylinder shaped when combined.  Then reassemble and refit.

The downside to this is that you've now got a bike with only one brake.  This would be stupid and foolhardy, as well as illegal in some parts of the world.
So fit a rear brake too - your cruiser bike likely has a mount for a rim brake, and your rim probably has a brake track. You'll need a brake caliper with pads, a lever for the handlebars, and some inner/outer cabling to join them, and sundries like cable ties/tape.

Second fix is to buy another rear wheel that isn't a coaster brake, and swap the wheels.  You'll need the same rolling size, and same Overlocknut dimension, and the same type/width of cassette mount, aka the freewheel hub.

Or, forgo the motor and ride your bicycle like normal.